# Plotting raster and vector data on same Plot

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, vector, plot

I have a raster and croped it by vector boundary. Vector reprojected to crs of the raster, but when I plot it does not show on the same figure?

Something with plotting extend, but how to make them match even if the coordinate system the same?

```py
# Process 

# Defines path to data
fire_boundary_path = os.path.join("...200_dd83.shp")
naip_2017_path = os.path.join("...70902.tif") 

fire_boundary = gpd.read_file(fire_boundary_path)

# Reproject fire boundary in the CRS as NAIP
fire_boundary_pr = fire_boundary.to_crs(epsg=26913)
fire_boundary_pr.crs

# Open/crop the rasters data sets
with rio.open(naip_2017_path) as naip_2017_src:
    naip_2017_crop, naip_2017_crop_meta = es.crop_image(naip_2017_src, fire_boundary_pr)

# To Plot
fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 14))
ep.plot_rgb(naip_2017_crop,
            ax=ax,
            rgb=[3, 0, 1],
            extent=naip_2017_crop_meta,
            title="Hw Plot#: NAIP 2017 Post Fire CIR Image")

# Including the Cold Springs fire boundary
fire_boundary_pr.plot(ax=ax, color="none",  edgecolor="blue", linewidth=3.1)

#plt.show()
```

Comment: print(fire_boundary_pr.crs)-->{'init': 'epsg:26913', 'no_defs': True}
naip_2017_crop_meta-- ....{'driver': 'GTiff',
 'dtype': 'uint8',
 'nodata': None,
 'width': 3370,
 'height': 1305,
 'count': 4,
 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(26913),
 'transform': Affine(1.0, 0.0, 457667.0,
        0.0, -1.0, 4426450.0)}